# Set inner div's height

Tags: css, html, height

How can I set the height of the inner div to be parent's height minus 15px?  The following doesn't work:  inner div expands beyond the bottom.  I tried using a table instead of inner div, but no dice.

```
<div style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:200px;height:50px;border:1px solid black">
  <div style="position:absolute;overflow:hidden;top:0;bottom:15px;left:0;width:50px;border:2px solid black">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
    <div>d</div>
    <div>e</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here are my solution constraints:
- The 'height:50px' in the parent is only illustrative; solution must work without knowing the parent's height
- IE7 onwards
- More css, less Javascript please

Thanks.

Comment: will you please upload a pic so that it becomes easy to understand what you want actually..

Comment: What do you want to happen with the inner div, should it expand due to it's content, and the outer div expand 15px beond that, or should the outer div have a specified height and the inner hide its content that can't be shown in the area it's given?

Comment: Why does the inner div need to be absolute positioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you want

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/qxRGn/)

**EDIT**: As you mentioned that outer DIV can have another children that may extend upto the bottom 15px
then just have a look at this [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/qxRGn/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
#outer {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
#inner {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

height:93.8% means: `height:93.8% = 100% - 15px`

```
<div style="position:relative;width:200px;height:50px;border:1px solid black">
  <div style="position:absolute;overflow:hidden;top:0;bottom:15px;left:0;width:50px;border:2px solid black; height:93.8%;">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
    <div>d</div>
    <div>e</div>
  </div>
</div>​
```

Hope this works for you!!!!